# For loop doesn't get finished

Tags: java, for-loop

```
    int length = Math.max(userOne.userName.length(), userTwo.userName.length());
    length = Math.max(length, 5);

    System.out.println("\nCurrent board:");
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
        for (int s=0; s<3; s++) {

            String box = "empty";
            if (boxes[i][s] == 1)
                box = userOne.userName;
            else if (boxes[i][s] == 10)
                box = userTwo.userName;

            if (box.length() < length) {
                for (int j=0; j<(length-box.length()); j++) {
                    box += " ";
                }
            }
            System.out.printf("[%s]",box);
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
```

The third loop **for (int j=0; j<(length-box.length()); j++)** loops incorrect number of time!!

For example, when it's supposed to loop 3 times, it only loops 2 times; and when it's supposed to loop 8 times, it only loops 4 times. I tried to print **j** and it seems that the loop never gets finished.

I assume this has something to do with Java's synchronization, but I have no idea how to solve it!

Comment: There's no "for (box.length() < length)" in your code. There is "for (int j=0; j<(length-box.length()); j++)", but how could we know what is wrong when you haven't defined "length-box" for us?

Comment: Sorry, thanks for pointing out, I corrected the code and the question.

Answer (score 1):

With each iteration, you are both incrementing `j` and decreasing `length-box.length()` since you are adding to `box`, so the loop will only run half as many times as you want it to (rounded up).

A `while` loop makes more sense here:

```
while (box.length() < length) {
    box += " ";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot of sense!

Answer (score 0):

You *increase the length* of `box` inside your code - making your **loop condition *dynamic***:

```
for (int j=0; j<(length-box.length()); j++) {
  box += " "; //makes box.length() increase!
}
```

If you wanted to target the `box` length as it was before the loop, calculate it before the loop:

```
int targetLength = length - box.length();
for (int j=0; j< targetLength; j++) {
  box += " "; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The box length changes during the loop and so your test changes.

Probably you need to save the initial box length in a variable and loop using that variable

```
int innerLength = length - box.length();
for (int j=0; j < innerLength; j++) {
    box += " ";
}
```